# Can I get Google Books "uid" with Google Sign In?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-api, google-books

I've created an app, that lets you sign in with Google and look at your collections of books.
The problem is that it works only with my personal uid that I put there after looking it up on https://books.google.com/books?uid=%5BMY_UID%5D

The problem is that in https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using it says:

> **User IDs** - Unique numeric values assigned to each user. These values are not necessarily the same ID value used in other Google services. Currently, the only way retrieve the user ID is to extract it from the selfLink in a Bookshelf resource retrieved with an authenticated request. Users can also obtain their own user ID from the Books site. A user cannot obtain the user ID for another user via the API or the Books site; the other user would have to share that information explicitly, by email for example.

Is there a way to get that uID? I don't know what it means to "extract it from the selfLink" or how to retrieve it with an authenticated request.

The app is programmed in Dart, and I've used Firebase to login with Google

Thanks in advance, this is the first time I post anything in here, if I did anything wrong/you need more info, let me know

I've tried to find people with similar problems, but couldn't find any.
I should try to make an authenticated request, but I don't know how to.

I'm expecting to get the uid for Google Books just by doing a login before the app starts.